# PHP dies after mail function

Tags: php

I'm trying to send a mail in a function and then return something afterward if succeded, but after running the mail function, which works, it seems like the PHP process just dies.

This is an example of what my code looks like right now

```
<?php

die(json_encode(someFunction('test@example.me')));

function someFunction($mail) {
  ..Some Code..

  ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
  error_reporting( E_ALL );
  $from = "no-reply@example.com";
  $to = $mail;
  $subject = "Test";
  $headers = "From: " . $from;
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

  $message = '
    <h1>Test message</h1>
  ';

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

  $r->success = true;
  return $r;
}
?>
```

And this doesn't return anything.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks in regards!

Comment: What is the variable $r?

Comment: It wouldn't "just die".  But it *could* fail with an error.  Or perhaps *could* produce no output.  What output are you expecting and why?  What is in your PHP logs?

Comment: @davidev `$r` is just a variable that the function returns

Comment: @David No errors at all, and I just except the output of an object with the value of 'success' equals to true, but I get no output

Comment: @TheDanishYoutuber: Where specifically are you checking for errors?  Where/how are you observing this output?  The code shown here would produce an error because `$r` is never defined.  And it wouldn't produce any output because `return` wouldn't be doing anything outside the context of a function.

Comment: With $r-> you are accessing functions or variables of an object.You have never initialized $r.

Comment: @davidev The code is just a snippet/example, I'm initializing the variable further up in the code

Answer (score 0):

You can't return without function. If you want to print anything just use echo or print_r.

```
 <?php
  ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
  error_reporting( E_ALL );

die(json_encode(someFunction('test@example.me')));

function someFunction($mail) {
  $from = "no-reply@example.com";
  $to = $mail;
  $subject = "Test";
  $headers = "From: " . $from;
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

  $message = '
    <h1>Test message</h1>
  ';

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  $r = new stdClass();
  $r->success = true;
  return $r;
}
?>
```

Comment: I have updated my question, the code I have given is just an example of my problem and not the real code.

Answer (score 0):

The error was the 2 lines

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
```

When i removed those, the code worked

Thanks for trying to help with solving my problem.